# htaccess reduce many lines to one?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(boards)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/([^./+])/?$ index.php?param0=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5&param5=$6 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(boards)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/([^./]+)/?$ index.php?param0=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(boards)/(.+)/(.+)/([^./]+)/?$ index.php?param0=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(boards)/(.+)/([^./]+)/?$ index.php?param0=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(boards)/([^./]+)/?$ index.php?param0=$1&param1=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(boards)/?$ index.php?param0=$1 [NC]
```

My question: would it be possible to combine those into just one rule? It's pretty annoying to maintain like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify `index.php`, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^boards/(.*) index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

and parse `$_GET['url']` yourself inside `index.php`.

Even better, you can do

```
RewriteRule ^boards/.* index.php [NC]
```

and then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` yourself in `index.php`.

Comment: this is quite a nice idea ~ i'll give it a try :)

Comment: i use this now:
RewriteRule ^(404|boards)/.*$ index.php?module=$1 [NC]
with all the 'module's i have in the brackets.